# How to get image using IdFTP with low quality?

Tags: delphi, ftp, firemonkey

I'm trying to get a couple of images using `idFTP`  to show in a `Tlistview` but the images are too big and the application gets too slow.

So I want to know if there are some way to execute `idFTP.get` with a determinate quality.

for example, when we use save an image we can put an parameter of quality

```
var param1: TBitmapCodecSaveParams;

begin
param1.Quality:=500;
image.SaveToFile(filename),@param1);
end;
```

Comment: The FTP protocol can only transfer files. It won't process images for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image quality is a function of the server, not of the client.
FTP protocol is just a file transport, this is the server which decide what is transmitted. Usually an FTP server just deliver existing file. Very seldom a FTP server generate "files" on the fly depending on the request.

So there is no solution to your specific problem, at least concerning the FTP transfer.

Of course you may resize the image once received. That is not difficult to do. GDI+ has thumbnail function you could use easily. You can create the thumbnail saving it in another filename so that you either use the thumbnail or the real file depending of the context.

Saving the image with high compression has you seems to try is another solution probably less efficient than creating a thumb nail.